# How to solve integration questions?

Tags: calculus, integration

How to solve these kind of questions:

$$\int{x^{-3}}d{(x^2)}$$

Is the answer for this question $$-\frac{x^{-1}}{2}$$?

Comment: It's hard to understand without MathJax: do you mean $\int x^{-3} d(x^2)$?

Comment: Yes exactly what I mean...... Thanks.

Comment: Viewed as a Riemann–Stieltjes integral, then since $g(x)=x^2$ is continuously differentiable, it equals $\int x^{-3} g’(x)dx = \int x^{-3} 2x dx = 2\int x^{-2} dx$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$I=\int x^{-3} d(x^2)= \int x^{-3} \frac{dx^2}{dx} dx= \int x^{-3}~ 2x~ dx =\int 2x^{-2} dx=\frac{-2}{x}+C$$

Comment: Is 1/dx= dx^-1?

Comment: In other words is (dx)^-1 = dx^-1?

Comment: More gnerally, $df=\frac{df}{dx} dx$